# PHP Compare whether strings are (almost) equal

Tags: php

I need to compare names which can be written in several ways. For example, a name like St. Thomas is sometimes written like St-Thomas or Sant Thomas. Preferably, I'm looking to build a function that gives a percentage of 'equalness' to a comparison, like some forums do (*this post is 5% edited* for example).

Comment: When you are not looking for percentage, another posibility is regexp matching. But to do this, one must know how much different the two names can be.

Comment: I think this is what you want: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2285201/php-smart-error-tolerating-string-comparison

Comment: [similar-text](http://www.php.net/manual/de/function.similar-text.php)

Comment: I think regular expression will be best solution

Answer (score 22, accepted):

PHP has two (main) built-in functions for this.

[`levenshtein`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.levenshtein.php) which counts how many changes (remove/add/replacements) are needed to produce string2 from string1. (lower is better)

and

[`similar_text`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.similar-text.php) which returns the number of matching characters (higher is better). Note that you can pass a reference as the third parameter and it'll give you a percentage.

```
<?php
    $originalPost = "Here's my question to stack overflou. Thanks /h2ooooooo";
    $editedPost = "Question to stack overflow.";
    $matchingCharacters = similar_text($originalPost, $editedPost, $matchingPercentage);
    var_dump($matchingCharacters); //int(25) 
    var_dump($matchingPercentage); //float(60.975609756098) (hence edited 40%)
?>
```

Comment: Ah the levenshtein function is perfect! Many thanks, will accept your answer in 6 minutes :-).

Comment: If you want something more advanced, check out [this essay](http://web.archive.org/web/20061007123913/http://www.english.upenn.edu/~jlynch/Computing/compare.html).

Comment: @gronostaj: Thanks... but for my application this should be good enough. Performance seems to be okay as well :-).

Answer (score 2):

The edit distance between two strings of characters generally refers to the Levenshtein distance.

http://php.net/manual/en/function.levenshtein.php

Answer (score 1):

```
$v1 = 'pupil';
$v2 = 'people';
# TRUE if $v1 & $v2 have similar  pronunciation
soundex($v1) == soundex($v2);  
# Same but it use a more accurate comparison algorithm                 
metaphone($v1) == metaphone($v2);               
# Calculate how many common characters between 2 strings
# Percent store the percentage of common chars
$common = similar_text($v1, $v2, $percent);     
# Compute the difference of 2 text                                                 
$diff = levenshtein($v1, $v2);
```

So, either `levenshtein($v1, $v2)` or `similar_text($v1, $v2, $percent)` will do it for you but still there is **tradeoff**. The complexity of the `levenshtein()` algorithm is `O(m*n)`, where n and m are the length of v1 and v2 (rather good when compared to `similar_text()`, which is `O(max(n,m)**3)`, but still expensive).

Answer (score 0):

Check out `levenshtein()`, which does what you want and is comparatively efficient (but not extremely efficient):
http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.levenshtein.php

Answer (score 0):

You can use different approaches.

You can use the `similar_text()` function to check for similarity.

OR

You can use `levenshtein()` function to find out...

> The Levenshtein distance is defined as the minimal number of characters you have to replace, insert or delete to transform str1 into str2

And then check for a reasonable threshold for your check.