# Equal to SQL's %like% but in PHP

Tags: php, sql, equals

Is there any function in PHP equal to SQL's %like%?

E.g.

```
$a = 'I drove the Car';
$b = 'i_drove_the_car';

if(like($a, $b))
{
 echo "The strings have an %like% match";
}
```

Comment: preg_match(), strstr()

Comment: strstr (http://www.php.net/strstr)?

Comment: possible duplicate of [PHP Compare whether strings are (almost) equal](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14832005/php-compare-whether-strings-are-almost-equal)

Answer (score 4):

Use [`strstr`](http://www.php.net/strstr), or, if you want case insensitive, [`stristr`](http://www.php.net/stristr):

```
if(strstr($a, $b)) {
    echo "$b is in $a";
}
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use regular expression, i.e. [preg_match](http://php.net/preg_match).

```
if (preg_match('#.*' . $b . '.*#/i', $a)) {
    echo 'smth';
}
```

Option `i` means case insensetive mathcing.

Answer (score 0):

In addition to the solutions above, if you are trying to do like with multiple parts like "%absc%ehf%", following script will help. You need to put different parts as different elements in array. Here, array would be array('absc','ehf')

```
// mainStr is the string you are searching and $partsArray holds the like parts 
// in array like explained above 
function like($mainStr, $partsArray) {
  if (empty($partsArray)) {
      return true;
  }

  $lastIndex = 0;
  // checks to see that strings exist after each other. In the example above, 
  // "%absc%ehf%" would first check the existence of absc and then if it exists 
  // it would continue checking the rest of the string for the rest of like parts 
  foreach($partsArray as $part) {
     $pos = strpos($mainStr, $part);
    if ( $pos === false || $pos < $lastIndex) {
        return false;
    } 
    $lastIndex += $pos + strlen($part); 
  }
  return true;

}
```

Comment: In that case preg_match would be better. Because that's what it's made for.

Comment: That is true but he would not have to worry about escaping weird characters or writing regex in general.